# Disable all write requests momentarily for DB migration in Firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a project that I need to restructure its Firestore DB. Currently, it's in daily use, so I need to disable all write (& maybe read) access for users only (not admin) until I can fully migrate the DB & make sure it's flawless.
My intuition was, that I could simply add a recursive statement to deny all incoming write requests. But it turns out that Firestore ORs overlapping match statements.

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow write:if false 
}
// More match statements for Admins & Users.
```

- What's the right approach here?
- Curious of the design decision behind ORing overlapping matches. Anding here would make more sense since it's more strict & leaves less room for un-intentional data leaks.

Comment: Try to add this statement on the end of rules. I'm not sure, but it might overwrite statements before this rule, you need to check it.

Comment: You can remove any other security rule statements for the time being and then  copy them back when you've migrated all your data.

Comment: @Dharmaraj But he wants to let users read data, this way he will let everyone read everything. ;/

Comment: @Mises in that case, can just set `allow write: if false;` for all the paths then. It'll still allow read as per old rules.

Comment: @Dharmaraj His database might contain sensitive data, and he might not want to every one read it.

Comment: If the read rules are not changed then I don't see how that can happen..

Comment: @Dharmaraj Read your first comment. You wrote that he needs to delete all rules and just not allow to write. This way, he will allow everyone to read everything in database, including sensitive personal data of other users.

Comment: @Dharmaraj You way is ok but only if he shoots down whole database and disable read and write operations.

Comment: @SaifHakeem As commented on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71858557/13171940), "_is a bad idea to pollute a project with conditionals to update data on the fly_".